# ShaderMask LinearGradient's stops strange behavior

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to fade both side (edges) of a content.

I use a `ShaderMask` along with a `LinearGradient`, it works great except that I don't understand why my `stops` are not centered correctly, I use `stops: [0.0, 0.05, 0.95, 1.0]` so that it should be faded `0.05` on each side, but I get the following (I added a `Container` gradient with same configuration for comparison):

[image: Container vs ShaderMask stops]

With debug paint mode :

[image: Container vs ShaderMask stops with debug paint enabled]

I use exactly the same stops for the `Container` and for the `ShaderMask` but get different results.

Of course I can try different `stops` values for the `ShaderMask` gradient until I got it centered but it seems like a hack.

Someone can explain ?

Here's the code if anyone want to give it a try :

```dart
return Container(
  height: 200,
  child: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      Expanded(
        child: ShaderMask(
          blendMode: BlendMode.modulate,
          shaderCallback: (Rect bounds) {
            return LinearGradient(
              begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
              end: Alignment.centerRight,
              colors: <Color>[Colors.transparent, Colors.white, Colors.white, Colors.transparent],
              stops: [0.0, 0.05, 0.95, 1.0],
              tileMode: TileMode.clamp,
            ).createShader(bounds);
          },
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.blue,
            child: ListView(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  "I'm a ShaderMask and I don't understand why my gradient don't behave like container's gradient. I'm a ShaderMask and I don't understand why my gradient don't behave like container's gradient.",
                  textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Expanded(
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
              begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
              end: Alignment.centerRight,
              colors: [Colors.transparent, Colors.blue, Colors.blue, Colors.transparent],
              stops: [0.0, 0.05, 0.95, 1.0],
              tileMode: TileMode.clamp,
            ),
          ),
          child: ListView(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                "I'm a Container and I don't understand why ShaderMask's gradient don't behave like mine. I'm a Container and I don't understand why ShaderMask's gradient don't behave like mine.",
                textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      )
    ],
  ),
);
```

I got the same result using `FractionalOffset` instead of `Alignment.centerRight` and `Alignment.centerRight`.

Comment: `createShader(Offset.zero & bounds.size)` or translate `bounds` to the left by `bounds.left` and to the top by `bounds.top`

Comment: Yes nice trick, it solves the problem thanks. My thought is that there should be an option for that in the `ShaderMask` widget so that we can set `Rect` offset.

Comment: it's not a trick, basically the `bounds` passed to `shaderCallback` are in global coordinates while you have to pass local `Rect` to `createShader` method

Comment: OK I see, so I could use `createShader(Rect.fromLTRB(0, 0, bounds.width, bounds.height))` which would do the same. Thanks, just add an answer with the explanation so I can accept it.

Comment: yes exactly - its the same but i think `Offset.zero & bounds.size` is more ... hmmm, sophisticated? ;-) feel free to write a self answer

Comment: Oh you deserve the answer's reward :) If you don't want or don't have time for it I will write one later. Best!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`shaderCallback` creates a `Shader` for a given `Rect`, and the `Rect` coordinates are relative to a given **origin**.

The shader callback is called with the current size of the child so that it can customize the shader to the size and **location** of the child.

It means we have to create the shader with a `Rect` based on the size of the child widget with no offset (basically the bounds passed to `shaderCallback` are in global coordinates while `createShader` is waiting for a local `Rect`).

So a simple solution is to create a new `Rect` with the right origin (offset) and bounds : `createShader(Rect.fromLTRB(0, 0, bounds.width, bounds.height))`.

Or a more sexy shorthand : `createShader(Offset.zero & bounds.size)` :

```dart
shaderCallback: (Rect bounds) {
  return LinearGradient(
    begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
    end: Alignment.centerRight,
    colors: <Color>[Colors.transparent, Colors.blue, Colors.blue, Colors.transparent],
    stops: [0.0, 0.04, 0.96, 1.0],
    tileMode: TileMode.clamp,
  ).createShader(Offset.zero & bounds.size);
},
```

Credits to pskink !