# How to adda gradient in the BottomBarItem icons in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, user-interface, dart

I have a bottom bar that has gradient icons. I have used ShaderMask to implement the gradient and the BottomNavBarType is fixed. I have assigned the colors **red and yellow** to the gradient icons but when I compile the code it shows me the gradient with the **default green/blue colors**. When I assign a value to the `selectedIconTheme` the gradient is a weird mix of the overlay of red yellow and the value.

I'm trying to implement the gradient on these icons and this is what the bar looks like:

[image]

And [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dYCn.png) is what I'm trying to achieve
This is the code for the BottomNavBar:

```
   bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        iconSize: 30,
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        showUnselectedLabels: true,
        showSelectedLabels: true,
        // selectedIconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.purple),
        onTap: (int index) {
          setState(() {
            _selectedIndex = index;
            _selectedIndex = index;
            _onItemTapped(index);
          });
        },
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            activeIcon: ShaderMask(
              shaderCallback: (Rect bounds) {
                return RadialGradient(
                  center: Alignment.topLeft,
                  radius: 0.5,
                   colors: <Color>[Colors.red, Colors.yellow],
                  tileMode: TileMode.repeated,
                ).createShader(bounds);
              },
              child: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.home),
            ),
            icon: new Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.home, color: Colors.grey),
            title: new Text('Home'),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            activeIcon: ShaderMask(
              shaderCallback: (Rect bounds) {
                return RadialGradient(
                  center: Alignment.topLeft,
                  radius: 1.0,
                  colors: <Color>[Colors.red, Colors.yellow],
                  tileMode: TileMode.mirror,
                ).createShader(bounds);
              },
              child: Icon(Icons.location_on),
            ),
            icon: Icon(Icons.location_on, color: Colors.grey),
            title: new Text('Nav'),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            activeIcon: ShaderMask(
              shaderCallback: (Rect bounds) {
                return RadialGradient(
                  center: Alignment.topLeft,
                  radius: 1.0,
                  colors: <Color>[Colors.red, Colors.yellow],
                  tileMode: TileMode.mirror,
                ).createShader(bounds);
              },
              child: Icon(Icons.notifications),
            ),
            icon: Icon(Icons.notifications, color: Colors.grey),
            title: Text('Notif'),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            activeIcon: ShaderMask(
              shaderCallback: (Rect bounds) {
                return RadialGradient(
                  center: Alignment.topLeft,
                  radius: 1.0,
                  colors: <Color>[Colors.red, Colors.yellow],
                  tileMode: TileMode.mirror,
                ).createShader(bounds);
              },
              child: Icon(Icons.account_circle),
            ),
            icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle, color: Colors.grey),
            title: Text("Profile"),
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

Edited:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Adding white color to `FontAwesomeIcons.home` in `ShaderMask` will fix the problem:

```
     BottomNavigationBarItem(
        activeIcon: ShaderMask(
          shaderCallback: (Rect bounds) {
            return RadialGradient(
              center: Alignment.topLeft,
              radius: 0.5,
               colors: <Color>[Colors.red, Colors.yellow],
              tileMode: TileMode.repeated,
            ).createShader(bounds);
          },
          child: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.home, ***color: Colors.white***),
        ),
        icon: new Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.home, color: Colors.grey),
        title: new Text('Home'),
      ),
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Tried it but now the icon is getting cropped for some reason. The gradient is working fine though.

Comment: Cropped... how?

Comment: The right part is getting cut off. Kindly see the edits

Comment: Try adding the same size to FontAwesomeIcons.home: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.home, color: Colors.white, size: 30)

Comment: Nope its still getting cut off :(

Comment: Apparently the problem is a combination of custom icon (FontAwesomeIcons.gamepad) and the ShaderMark: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59705860/shadermask-lineargradients-stops-strange-behavior
I think you should open another issue, the gradient has been resolved, right?